# Count the occurrence of each letter in a sentence using a stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I'd like to count the occurrence of each letter in a sentence and store the result in `Map<Character, Integer>`. This could be easily done using a simple loop, but as an exercise I'd like to write it using a stream. I thought of using `collect(toMap())` to produce a map whose values are the characters itself (so I used `Function.identity()`) and the number of occurrences. I've come up with the following (non-compiling) code:

```
"a simple sentence".chars()                
.collect(toMap(Collectors.partitioningBy(Function.identity(), 
Collectors.counting())));
```

Comment: And what is the question? If your code is not working, please describe in which ways?,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
String string ="a simple sentence";
Map<String, Long> map = 
 Arrays.stream(string.split("")).
 collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: `c -> c` could be `Function.identity()`

Comment: I prefer `c -> c` over `Function.identity()`, since it's shorter and clean.

Answer (score 3):

You're actually close, to finish off what you've started, you need to use the `mapToObj` intermediate operation and a `groupingBy` collector instead of `partitioningBy` as follows:

```
Map<Character, Long> result = "a simple sentence".chars()
                .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        counting()));
```

or if you want the map keys to be strings then you can do:

```
Map<String, Long> result = "a simple sentence".chars()
                .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
                .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        counting()));
```

or if you want the occurrence of all characters except the whitespace character:

```
Map<String, Long> result = "a simple sentence".chars()
                .filter(c -> !Character.isSpaceChar(c))
                .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
                .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        counting()));
```

or using a pattern:

```
Map<String, Long> result = 
     Pattern.compile("\\s+")
            .splitAsStream("a simple sentence")
            .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("")))
            .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        counting()));
```

a more efficient version using pattern:

```
Map<String, Long> result = 
     Pattern.compile("") 
            .splitAsStream("a simple sentence")
            .filter(s -> !s.trim().isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: The last variant is a waste of resources. Why do splitting the string into word strings, to do another splitting (inconsistently using `String.split`) into letter strings on them? Why not use `Pattern.compile("") .splitAsStream("a simple sentence")` in the first place?

Comment: @Holger note that specific solution removes whitespace characters from the result. if you're suggesting `Pattern.compile("") 
            .splitAsStream("a simple sentence")
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        Collectors.counting()));` then this will maintain the whitespace characters which is not my intention there. However, yes one can simply add a `filter` to remove them before grouping... instead of `.flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("")))`

Comment: Would be a baroque solution to remove white-space (and I, as a reader, wasn’t even aware that it is a goal). So yes, I’d just use `filter`. Or you use `Pattern.compile("\\s+|(?<!\\s)").splitAsStream(…)` to split into characters and remove white-space in one go.